# Angular 5 - How to add Conditional Fields on Form Value Change

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I working on applying conditional field logic. Where two fields are dependant on their value.

**Requirement:**
Let's say, we've a radio button with following values:

> **Do you want to format this code:** o Yes o No

If user selects, No, nothing happens. If user selects Yes, there would be another field which will as:

> **Select formatting type:** o HTML o PHP o Javascript

I'm using https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms way for generating form, where we pass the settings to FormGroup and it generates a form.

Way I tried:

```
this.form.valueChanges
.subscribe(values => {
    if(value['require_formatting'] === 'yes') {
        this.form.addControl('formatting_type', myFormControl); // Add new form control
    }
});
```

This is unfortunately, giving me "Maximum call stack size exceeded error. When I add setTimeout before adding form control it works well but then console gets messy with inifinite number of unnecessary calls.

Comment: Why are you using reactive-forms. If you just did template driven this would be as easy as adding `[(ngModel)]="shouldFormat"` to the radio button (declaring should format in the component `shouldFormat: boolean`) and adding `*ngIf="shouldFormat"` to the conditional field you'd like... Not really an answer but that is how I would do this.

Comment: That's because, we are using "Model Driven Form" where we get the field settings from an API and based on those setting, we attach or detach validators. That makes it so easy to create a form. I've prepared my own form builder module which is working pretty well when there are "no" conditional fields.

Comment: Ok well that makes sense, I suppose that is the prescribed use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the code to something like this:

```
this.form.valueChanges
.subscribe(values => {
    if(value['require_formatting'] === 'yes' && this.form.get('formatting_type')) {
        this.form.addControl('formatting_type', myFormControl); // Add new form control
    }
});
```

It should get rid of the stack overflow by only running the code in the if statement once.

The issue is the code inside the if statement calls the observable's next function in an infinite loop. This way it will be run a finite number of times.

Comment: Ok let me try this.

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks mate.

Comment: Better to use https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get and check if control exists inside form.