# Angular adding form controls to reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-forms, angular-validation

Im am trying to have a textarea required when the the radio option Yes is choosen, but it does sort of work

if i choose Yes i get

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

if i choose No then Yes i get

> Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {SorDataService} from '../sor-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-intervention-strategies',
  templateUrl: './intervention-strategies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./intervention-strategies.component.css']
})
export class InterventionStrategiesComponent implements OnInit {

  public form: FormGroup;

  /** Page 5 */
  constructor(public data: SorDataService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      csc_dynamicsecurity: [null, Validators.required],
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(values => {

      if (values['csc_dynamicsecurity'] === true) {
        this.form.addControl('csc_dynamicsecurityexplanation', new FormControl('', Validators.required)); // Add new form control
      }
      else if (values['csc_dynamicsecurity'] === false) {
        this.form.removeControl('csc_dynamicsecurityexplanation');
      }
    });
  }

  public next() {

    if (this.form.valid) {
      alert('valid');
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to add form validation to a field that is conditionally added to the form

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

  <div class="app-radio-field app-field-required" [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('csc_dynamicsecurity')">

    <h5 i18n>Dynamic Security and Staff Presence?</h5>

    <mat-radio-group [formControl]="form.get('csc_dynamicsecurity')">
      <mat-radio-button color="primary" [value]="true"
                        i18n>Yes
      </mat-radio-button>

      <mat-radio-button color="primary" [value]="false"
                        i18n>No
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </div>

  <mat-form-field class="full-width" *ngIf="form.get('csc_dynamicsecurity').value === true">
  <textarea matTextareaAutosize matInput required i18n-placeholder placeholder="Explain"
            [formControl]="form.get('csc_dynamicsecurityexplanation')"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

I also tried adding `&& this.form.get('csc_dynamicsecurityexplanation')` to the subscribe as i had sen others suggest and this seems to fix the stack error but i still get the below error .. Im not quite sure im doing this right .. any help is appriciated

> Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

```
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(values => {

      if (values['csc_dynamicsecurity'] === true && this.form.get('csc_dynamicsecurityexplanation')) {
        this.form.addControl('csc_dynamicsecurityexplanation', new FormControl('', Validators.required)); // Add new form control
      }
      else if (values['csc_dynamicsecurity'] === false && this.form.get('csc_dynamicsecurityexplanation')) {
        this.form.removeControl('csc_dynamicsecurityexplanation');
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of observing `form` valueChanges, you could subscribe to `'csc_dynamicsecurity'` formControl `valueChanges`. That should fix your errors. Adding new `formControls` within `form.valueChanges` could result in infinite loop and hence leading to `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
 this.form.get('csc_dynamicsecurity').valueChanges.subscribe(values => {

      if (values === true) {
        this.form.addControl('csc_dynamicsecurityexplanation', new FormControl('', Validators.required), ); // Add new form control
      }
      else if (values === false) {
        this.form.removeControl('csc_dynamicsecurityexplanation');
      }
    });
  }
```

See this working [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-infinite-form-valuechanges?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: Much thanks.. it perfect, it works like a charm. this post is what threw me off https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729092/angular-5-how-to-add-conditional-fields-on-form-value-change

Comment: That solution in the link did not work for you because you missed the second condition on `if`. In your case, there is no reason to watch for entire `form`. You are just concerned about the radio `form control` value.

Comment: wasnt sure i needed to accept the answer thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a generic solution to the problem based on @Amit's code, hopeful it can help some one

```
public ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      csc_dynamicsecurity: [null, Validators.required],
    });

    const fnBool = (input) => {
      return (value) => {
        if (value === true) {
          this.form.addControl(input, new FormControl('', Validators.required)); // Add new form control
        }
        else if (value === false) {
          this.form.removeControl(input);
        }
      };
    };

    this.form.get('csc_dynamicsecurity').valueChanges.subscribe(fnBool('csc_dynamicsecurityexplanation'));
  }
```